# PCMCIA Does Not Work on Dell Latitude under Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dell-latitude, pcmcia

PCMCIA cards do not work on Dell Latitude e5510 under Windows XP.  Works fine on Windows 7.  Cards are recognized by Device Manager but do not work correctly.  For example, CF adapter does not recognize when a card is inserted and network card is unable to obtain an IP address.

Other systems that may be affected:

Latitude E4310
Latitude E5410
Latitude E5510
Latitude E6410
Latitude E6410 ATG
Latitude E6510
Dell Precision Mobile WorkStation M4500

Comment: Wow you were really quick to ask and answer your own question...

Answer (score 1):

Locate the following key in regedit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Pcmcia\Parameters
```

Add a `REG_DWORD` named `IrqRouteToPciController` and assign a value of 8.

Reboot and try PCMCIA again.

Comment: This did nothing. I have a E5520 running XP, and if you look in the device Manager, under PCMCIA adapters, it has one entry, but it's a Generic Cardbus Controller.